# How to mask last few characters in textbox using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Inside a partialview, there is a textbox field binded to a model property. This text box is meant for sensitive information. So,I would like to mask the last few characters with asterisk(*).

If I use EditorFor() with input type set to "password", then all the characters are masked, which doesn't serve my purpose.

My desired functionality is
  1) The last 4 characters in the text box should be displayed as ****(even while user enters the input, not just out of text box focus
  2) The data sent to the controller must contain the actual value.

Please suggest.

Comment: why can't you use string.Format function or if this is in a web page

Comment: There is no html form control that does that (and nothing in MVC). You would need to write your jquery plugin

Comment: wouldn't you want to mask everything and show only the last 4 characters..?

Comment: @MethodMan Sadly, that's the requirement and there is hardly anything that I can do in changing it

Comment: I will post something that you can use to get started and play around with. also `the last 4 characters should be displayed and the first 5 chars should be * if it were SSN # for example` what type of data is going into that box..

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you, I will try writing one.

Comment: @MethodMan It would be helpful if you can provide that sample, thanks !

Comment: @zeroCool I posted something  to get you stared very straight forward :)

Comment: @zeroCool: This is a very good question. But I cannot think of a way of achieving this without using jquery. Your answer is below.

Comment: Answer edited. I am not familiar with SSN. But you should be able to add more validations using the below code.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Just noticed you have already come up with a similar idea. But trust me, I didn't see it before posting my comment/code. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way.

```
    @model WebApplication1.Models.MyModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<br/>
<label>Enter your SSN</label>
<input type="text" id="visiblesecret"/>
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.MySensitiveField,new{@id="secret"})

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('body').on('keyup', '#visiblesecret', function(event) {
            var typedtext = $('#visiblesecret').val();
            $('#secret').val(typedtext);
            if (typedtext.length >= 7) {
                var len = typedtext.length;
                var nonSecretChars = '';
                var secret = '';
                switch (len) {
                    case 7:
                        nonSecretChars = typedtext.substring(0, len - 1);
                        secret = nonSecretChars + '*';
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        nonSecretChars = typedtext.substring(0, len - 2);
                        secret = nonSecretChars + '**';
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        nonSecretChars = typedtext.substring(0, len - 3);
                        secret = nonSecretChars + '***';
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        nonSecretChars = typedtext.substring(0, len - 4);
                        secret = nonSecretChars + '****';
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert("Invalid SSN");
                        $('#secret').val('');
                        $('#visiblesecret').val('');
                        return;
                }
                $('#visiblesecret').val(secret);
                //alert('You entered ' + $('#secret').val());
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hold the value of the last 4 just in case your requirements change do the following

```
//var last4 = myString.Substring(myString.Length - 4, 4);
```

If you want to store the first 5 characters do the following

```
//myString.Substring(myString.Length - 9, 5)

var maskDelim = new string('*', 4);
var myString = "123456789";
var maskResults = myString.Substring(0, 5);
maskResults = maskResults + maskDelim;
```

Comment: That only takes care of the initial display - it does not take care of _"even while user enters the input"_